# Error al mezclar versiones en el Gradle App con librerias Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle

Estoy intentando sincronizar las librerías `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'` y `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'`en el `Gradle` pero me salta el error de esas librerías no corresponden a las demás.

Estas librerías de `Firebase` son la última versión y estoy usando `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` con `Android Studio 3.2`. He intentado cambiar la verión de `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` pero sigue apareciendo el error.

Error: `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.juancortesgarcia.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

La librería que da error es `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: No sé si ha sido un error al pegar el código, pero esta línea está escrita con error, al menos aquí en la pregunta: `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'`  la parte de `espresso-`  y `core:3.0.2` parecen no estar juntas.

Comment: Yo tengo la configuración como la tuya. De hecho tenía la versión 26 y actualicé a la 28. El error que me dio era porque el entorno de Android Studio no estaba actualizado para la versión 28. Si tienes AS actualizado no debería darte error, si es que ese es tu `gradle` completo. No hay nada incompatible en él. Teniendo en cuenta que la línea sobre la que te hablé en mi comentario anterior es errónea, al menos como la presentas aquí.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar `Android Studio` a la última versión `3.2.1` y sigue apareciendo el error.

Comment: Que extraño. ¿Tienes todos los plugin de Android actualizados? Si pasas a la v. 27 desaparece el error? Yo tengo una configuración parecida y ningún problema.

Comment: Vale ya lo solucioné. Para que funcionen las versiones  `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'` `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'` se corresponde con la versión `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

Comment: Juan no es del todo cierto lo que dices. Yo tengo la versión 28  y de firebase la misma que tú, que es la última versión. No es que la versión 16 de firebase sólo funcione con la API 26. Yo lo que creo que no tienes es el SDK de la versión 28, o falta instalar parte de él. Eso lo puedes revisar en el menú `Tools`, yendo luego a `SDK Manager`. Allí hay varias opciones y pestañas.

Comment: Pues en Agosto de 2019 tengo un problema muy similar... Intento introducir publicidad en mi app por primera vez. Sigo las instrucciones de Google Admob pero en cuanto añado la línea "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'" se produce un error en la linea "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'" Y no consigo resolverlo de ninguna forma.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien comentas, estas son las últimas versiones hasta el día de hoy, Octubre 2018 :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

pero veo que estas usando :

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

**Actualmente existen varia dependencias que aún no están preparadas para funcionar correctamente con esta versión del SDK**, por lo tanto te sugiero 
cambiar a :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

y usar la librería de soporte:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

esta configuración te puedo asegurar funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Chicos, yo tengo el mismo problema que el compañero, pero estamos  a julio de 2019, no se si la configuracion dada por el compañero ya estará obsoleta por lo smeses que han pasado. Este es mi codigo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId "com.livecity.livecity.livecitycliente"
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'   //cortar la imagen con cropper
    //compile 'com.github.yalantia:uceop:2.3.3-native'                //cortar la imagen con ucrop
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```